# Access based on WHERE Yes/No field

Tags: vb.net, updates

I want to update my access db, based on a Yes/No field.
The string which I want to use is:

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE [Reactie] SET DoubleCheck = '1' WHERE Online = '0'"
```

When I use this I get the following error:

```
"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression.     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()     at Brady_Check_In_Out.Database.reactie(String sector, String type, String checked)"
```

When I would remove the WHERE part, or want to update on another field like:

```
   sqlstr = "UPDATE [Reactie] SET DoubleCheck = '1' WHERE Sector = 'MG'"
```

Then it works perfectly.

Any ideas why?
Btw, I also tried: WHERE Online = 'False', but no luck.

Comment: what kind of datatype has the "Online"-column?  maybe you can try: 0 instead of '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Online" is a boolean try:

> sqlstr = "UPDATE [Reactie] SET DoubleCheck = '1' WHERE Online = 0"

Comment: Wow, that was simple... I find it strange however that we need the '' to SET something, but not for the WHERE function.

Thanks for your fast answer, I would vote you up, but I don't have enough points to do it.

Comment: @GetDeWilde - if that answer helpded you plz just mark as "Solution" ;) - thx

Comment: Done!
I would Vote you up as well, but too little points!

Either way, thanks again!